# Testing a subclass when superclass uses a private method

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spock

I have an abstract class `Foo` that contains a public method `abc()` and a private method `xyz()` used in `abc()` that generates a random string. What `abc()` returns depends on the return value of `xyz()`.

I also have a subclass `Bar` that extends `Foo`.

I would like to test `Bar` using `abc()`. However, since I don't know the result of `xyz()`, I don't know what `abc()` will return.

The code looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    
    public String abc() {
        *xyz() called here*
    }

    private String xyz() {
        *Generates a random string*
    }

}
```

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
}
```

I tried stubbing or mocking but it doesn't work. I presume that the design of `Foo` should be changed but am not sure how. I use Spock. Any advice?

Comment: @AndyTurner My bad, it should be the other way around. I've already edited the OP. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: There's a couple solutions that immediately pop into mind: 1) Make `Foo#xyz` a `protected final` method, 2) Make `Bar#abc` use the result of `super.abc();` to determine its returned value. Keep in mind that per Liskov's Subtitution Principle, you should ensure that a `Bar` behaves like a `Foo`, and in that manner, `Bar#abc` should not act differently from the expected behavior of `Foo#abc` (to the extent of the same behavior, but perhaps a different "variety").

Comment: Why don't you move xyz to a separate class RandomStringGenerator and than mock it?

Comment: `I tried stubbing or mocking but it doesn't work.` Could you explain what doesn't work? Also please share more what you are actually want to test? You can use `Spy` for partial mocking to stub the value returned by `abc()` but if that is correct approach is hard to tell with so little information.

Comment: Don't try to mock private methods. If you cannot cover your class under test using its public API, its design is broken and you should refactor. When you say that the result of `abc()` depends on the result of `xyz()`, you should ask yourself what the result of `xyz()` depends on and how to achieve the result you need for testing via `Foo`'s public API. If you need a more specific answer, please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just pseudo code with empty method bodies.